# Selenium cannot find element, allthough xpath works in developer tools

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on creating a script that creates a shared drive after logging in to google. I got to the add members' email and when I try to enter an email I get an error saying the following element does not exist. If anyone has any idea why this is not working correctly please be sure to let me know, thanks.

Forgot to mention, that the xpath does work in developer tools.

```
time.sleep(10)
enterEmails = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='quantumWizAutocompleteInputHint exportAutocompleteInput exportAutocompleteInputHint']")
enterEmails.send_keys('example@example.com')
```

Comment: the other answer, and it's comments, are wrong. you're `find_element_by_xpath` *should* work fine. however, there is some other issue involved. what is the exact exception you are getting? `NoSuchElement`? or `ElementNotVisibleException`?

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@class='quantumWizAutocompleteInputHint exportAutocompleteInput exportAutocompleteInputHint']"}
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.88)

Comment: Either it's not there or it's in an iframe

Comment: It's 100% there, I checked it with developer tools.

Comment: I doubt the element may be present in an iframe. Did you checked it?

Comment: @MaxwellTan unfortunately without seeing the full HTML or knowing the URL of the page you are trying to parse, there isn't probably a whole lot else people here can do to help. as others have said, there's a chance the element is in an iframe so i would check the DOM in developer tools and see if the element is nested in one. if so, you'll have to switch to the iframe as one of the other answers mentions.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to space contained in between classnames.

try below:

```
enterEmails = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@class,'quantumWizAutocompleteInputHint exportAutocompleteInput exportAutocompleteInputHint')]")
enterEmails.send_keys('example@example.com')
```

Comment: Same error.

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[contains(@class,'quantumWizAutocompleteInputHint exportAutocompleteInput exportAutocompleteInputHint')]"}

Comment: This will catch all the matched elements of type input and others. You can also try sharing the DOM structure  to get more accurate response. enterEmails = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'quantumWizAutocompleteInputHint exportAutocompleteInput exportAutocompleteInputHint')]")
enterEmails.send_keys('example@example.com')

Comment: <input class="quantumWizAutocompleteInputHint exportAutocompleteInput exportAutocompleteInputHint" disabled="true" aria-hidden="true" jsname="A51lKb" value="Add names or email addresses" dir="ltr">

Comment: <input class="quantumWizAutocompleteInputText exportAutocompleteInput" type="text" autocomplete="off" aria-label="members" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" role="combobox" jsname="dSO9oc" jsaction="input:YPqjbf; keydown:I481le; click:cOuCgd" autofocus="" aria-owns="nngdp22" aria-controls="nngdp22">

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me in the local.

Sample HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
 <input class="quantumWizAutocompleteInputText exportAutocompleteInput" type="text" autocomplete="off" aria-label="members" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" role="combobox" jsname="dSO9oc" jsaction="input:YPqjbf; keydown:I481le; click:cOuCgd" autofocus="" aria-owns="nngdp22" aria-controls="nngdp22">
 
 <input class="quantumWizAutocompleteInputHint exportAutocompleteInput exportAutocompleteInputHint" disabled="true" aria-hidden="true" jsname="A51lKb" value="Add names or email addresses" dir="ltr">
</body>
</html>
```

**xpath:** `//input[contains(@class,'quantumWizAutocompleteInputText')]`

**Python Line of code:**

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@class,'quantumWizAutocompleteInputText')]").send_keys('example@example.com')`

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The element you try to find may be inside an iframe thats why the program throws an error. For this, you need to switch to that frame by the code:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(<frame_name>)
```

Hope this helps.